# String Extraction using regexp

Tags: java, regex, string, scala

how to convert the string to List[String] where it can have special characters in scala/java

Input =>`[ "Stack", "Overflow", "flow"]`

output => `List("Stack","Overflow","flow")`

Comment: Could you be more specific in your input? Do you want to split the input string to list based on regular expression?

Comment: Are you saying that `[ "Stack", "Overflow", "flow"]` is one single String?

Comment: Looks like JSON, so you could use a json parser like jackson to read it as a `List<String>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of existing Json parsing libraries.

Here is example with upickle:

```scala
import upickle.default._

val res = read[List[String]](""" [ "Stack", "Overflow", "flow"] """)
println(res) //List(Stack, Overflow, flow)
```

Each of Regexp/split sollutions has it's own problems (see in fiddle below).

fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/sH8KPLG/4

```xml
----------------------------------------
FOR INPUT:  [ "Stack", "Overflow", "flow"] 
----------------------------------------
scalway : (ok) List(Stack, Overflow, flow)
Tim     : (ok) List(Stack, Overflow, flow)
jwvh_2  : (ok) List(Stack, Overflow, flow)
jwvh_1  : (!!) List("Stack", "Overflow", "flow")

----------------------------------------
FOR INPUT:  [ "Sta ck", "Overflow+", " flow"] 
----------------------------------------
scalway : (ok) List(Sta ck, Overflow+,  flow)
Tim     : (!!) List(Sta, ck, Overflow, flow)
jwvh_2  : (ok) List(Sta ck, Overflow+,  flow)
jwvh_1  : (!!) List("Sta ck", "Overflow+", " flow")

----------------------------------------
FOR INPUT:  [ "Stack", "Overf\"low", "flow"] 
----------------------------------------
scalway : (ok) List(Stack, Overf"low, flow)
Tim     : (!!) List(Stack, Overf, low, flow)
jwvh_2  : (!!) List(Stack, Overf\, , )
jwvh_1  : (!!) List("Stack", "Overf\", ", ")
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear if you want to retain the quote marks or not.

```
val input = """[ "Stack", "Overflow", "flow" ]"""

"\"[^\"]*\"".r.findAllIn(input).toList
//res0: List[String] = List("Stack", "Overflow", "flow")

"\"([^\"]*)\"".r.findAllMatchIn(input).map(_.group(1)).toList
//res1: List[String] = List(Stack, Overflow, flow)
```

Comment: this will fail if you have espaced quote sign: `[ "Stack", "Overf\"low", "flow"]`

Comment: But if you are sure that you have not such escaped quote, then it should work well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple option:

```
val input = """[ "Stack", "Overflow", "flow"]"""

val output = input.split("\\W+").filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

`split` splits the string into words separated by non-word characters.

`filter` removes any empty strings at the start/end of the result.

Comment: not safe at all. It will produce unexpected results in such cases `[ "Sta ck", "Overflow+", " flow"]`

Comment: It is clear what results this will give. What is not clear is what the OP actually wants.

Comment: No it is not. You assume that example input is all what Kishorekumar Yakkala was asked for... but it probably isn't. You also assume that someone who takes answer from StackOverflow understands it... but it is not always true. Of course you have described what your `split` does but still... result will be wrong for most inputs. It is even more problematic that it works for simple cases because someone will test it with such examples and then throw it to production... because it worked.

Comment: @Scalway You need to look more carefully at who is making assumptions here :)